# How to put and retrieve bit fields in a QByteArray without pain?

Tags: c++, qt

How to put and retrieve bit fields in a QByteArray without pain?

Comment: Since current CPUs cannot address memory spaces smaller than one byte (`sizeof(char)`), you cannot access a specific bit without bit shifts and masks. Of course you could use specific structures/libraries for this purpose but keep in mind that they will still use bit shifts under the hood.

Comment: Since the question is blocked and the answer cannot be given, the answer will lie [here](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1081019/265725)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an article on the Qt wiki for that ([Working with raw data](https://wiki.qt.io/Working_with_Raw_Data)), I hope it could be helpful.

Basically, it says:

> A `QBitArray` represents an array of individual bits. You can test and
>   modify each bit individually using the operator`[]`, thus avoiding
>   having to use bit shifts and complex masks combined with logical
>   operators [...]

Obviously, we need a way to convert a `QByteArray` into a `QBitArray`. The article provides a solution to this too:

```
QByteArray bytes = ...;

// Create a bit array of the appropriate size
QBitArray bits(bytes.count()*8);

// Convert from QByteArray to QBitArray
for(int i=0; i<bytes.count(); ++i) {
    for(int b=0; b<8;b++) {
        bits.setBit( i*8+b, bytes.at(i)&(1<<(7-b)) );
    }
}
```

And, similarly:

```
QBitArray bits = ...;

// Resulting byte array
QByteArray bytes;

// Convert from QBitArray to QByteArray
for(int b=0; b<bits.count();++b) {
    bytes[b/8] = (bytes.at(b/8) | ((bits[b]?1:0)<<(7-(b%8))));
}
```